# How pixiJS and socket.io can work togheter? (General question)

Tags: socket.io, pixi.js

I am starting with pixiJS, following the book: "Learn Pixi.js
Create Great Interactive Graphics for Games and the Web" - Rex van der Spuy
. I understand how the following general structure of a basic game works,

```
let state = play;

function gameLoop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  state();
  renderer.render(stage);
}
function play() {
//Do something
}
```

What I don't know is how to modify the above to include client-server communications.
I want to use the soket.io library for this purpose. I want to change the state of the game through interaction with the user. The user presses a button, a request is fired to the server, the server receives it and sends some data in response, the client receives that data and the game continues. But socket.io communication is an asynchronous process. If I wait for the data to be received within the gameLoop, the game will surely crash whenever I want to use it before it arrives from the server. How should I implement socket communication together with the gameLoop so that the state of the game is correctly updated with the data that comes from the server?
Thanks, I appreciate any helpful comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two problems here:

### First problem - separation of "game logic loop" and "animation loop":

In the code snippet which you pasted in your question your game logic ("state()" call) is tied to rendering logic / animation. This way the game logic update (state) needs to wait for rendering, and rendering needs to wait for game logic update. Also what if for example: the "game logic update" is very heavy and should be called every 0.2 seconds - so not so often as rendering which happens ~60 times per seconds (60 FPS)?

What can help to solve this issue is to have 2 independent loops - lets call them: "game logic loop" and "animation loop".

```
function gameLogicLoop() 
  updateState();
  setTimeout(function () { gameLogicLoop(); },  200); // ms
}

function animationLoop() {
  prepareStageFromState();
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  renderer.render(stage);
}

// start both loops:
gameLogicLoop();
animationLoop();
```

This way the `animationLoop()` is called ~60 times per second, and `gameLogicLoop()` 5 times per second (every 0.2 seconds).

When you use such approach then you should respect following rules:

- whatever happens in `gameLogicLoop()` should not modify rendering / animation / graphics. Here you can for example:

  - change gold amount of player
  - change position of player in game map (like: "moving from tile D3 to tile D4" - not "pixel x/y" on screen)
  - create new monsters on map etc.
- whatever happens in `animationLoop()` should not modify game logic. Here you can for example:

  - draw gold counter on screen (you take amount of gold from game state data)
  - animate player movement from tile D3 to tile D4 (you can calculate pixel x/y from tiles from game state data)
  - show new monster on map (maybe with some animation).

As an example please check this simple script: https://jsfiddle.net/urvdhw8b/

- notice `gameLogicLoop` function - handles update of game state data (every 1 second).
- notice `animationLoop` and `prepareStageFromState` functions - handles rendering (~60 FPS).
- additionally game state data is modified by:

```
    // Click on circle should increase number of lumberjack huts:
    circle.on('click', function(event) {
        lumberjackHutCount++;
    });
```

The "on click" event which increases number of lumberjack huts when circle is clicked is happening "outside" of both loops - because is independent asynchronous event (mouse click). We can classify this as game logic too.

### Second problem - client/server communication:

> The user presses a button, a request is fired to the server, the server receives it and sends some data in response, the client receives that data and the game continues. But socket.io communication is an asynchronous process.

You can handle this using events (similar as `circle.on('click'...` above) and in `gameLogicLoop()`. The `animationLoop()` should not handle any client/server communication or call anything in "socket.io" etc - it should just render things on screen basing on game state data.

We could create following event for the "lumberjack" script above:

```
// on client side:
socket.on("lumberjack_huts_updated", (data) => {
  lumberjackHutCount = data.newLumberjackHutCount;
});


// on server side:
hutCount++;
...
socket.emit("lumberjack_huts_updated", { newLumberjackHutCount: hutCount });
```

This way when client will receive "lumberjack_huts_updated" message from server then it will update game state data (`lumberjackHutCount` variable). This will happen asynchronously - independent from `animationLoop()`.

Of course this is just simple example and for sure you will find new ways to improve and optimize it as you progress. For example: in the client you can consider queueing incoming messages from server (store them in some array), and then process them inside `gameLogicLoop()`.

Here you have few tutorials/docs/projects related to this topic and to "multiplayer" - which is most popular use case for games that utilize client/server communication:

- "How To Build A Multiplayer Browser Game" by Alvin Lin - (is also about socket.io):

  1. Part 1: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-a-multiplayer-browser-game-4a793818c29b
  2. Part 2: https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-build-a-multiplayer-browser-game-part-2-2edd112aabdf
- (also socket.io) https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone/wiki/Game-Architecture
- https://github.com/adityaravishankar/last-colony
- "Writing A Multiplayer Text Adventure Engine In Node.js":

  1. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/12/multiplayer-text-adventure-engine-node-js/
  2. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/10/multiplayer-text-adventure-engine-node-js-part-2/?utm_source=gamedevjsweekly&utm_medium=email
  3. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/10/multiplayer-text-adventure-engine-node-js-part-3/
- https://github.com/js13kGames/js13kserver

  - uses socket.io - please check https://github.com/js13kGames/js13kserver/blob/master/public/client.js
  - it is game server for the [js13kGames Competition](http://js13kgames.com/)
- "Networking in C++" by javidx9 - not javascript, but he exaplains client/server, multiplayer etc concepts in understandable way :)

  1. [Networking in C++ Part #1: MMO Client/Server, ASIO & Framework Basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hNdkYInj4g)
  2. [Networking in C++ Part #2: MMO Client/Server, ASIO, Sockets & Connections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbjxGvrDrbw)
  3. [Networking in C++ Part #3: MMO Client/Server Framework, Tweaks & Client Validation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHowZ3bWsio)

Comment: domis86, thank you very much, I really appreciate your time. You gave me a lot to think about and learn in your detailed answer, more a true lesson that a simple reply I would say. Thanks again.

Comment: Im glad i could help :)