# How can I optimize WebGL (pixi.js) rendering in requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, animation, webgl, pixi.js, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to improve performance of animation. My animation includes 3 different parts: fadein, fadeout and scale transformation effect. But they start not synchroniously. Now I use 3 requestAnimationFrame calls each of them call WebGL-renderer (I'm using pixi.js). My main question is it a good idea to improve performance to create something like buffer where I'll collect renderer calls and do rendering synchronyously? And If it is I'd like to know how to do it rightly. Thanks.

Animation:

```
export function animateScaling(
  timestamp,
  container,
  renderer,
  targetScale,
  currentScale,
  start,
  delta
) {
  var progress;
  if (start === null) start = timestamp;
  progress = timestamp - start;
  var lambda = progress / delta;

  if (lambda > 1) lambda = 1;
  lambda = lambda * (0.4 + lambda * (2.2 + lambda * -1.6));
  container.children.forEach(function (markerSprite) {
    markerSprite.scale.set(
      currentScale + lambda * (targetScale - currentScale)
    );
  });
  renderer.render(container);
  if (progress < delta) {
    var frame = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      animateScaling(
        Date.now(),
        container,
        renderer,
        targetScale,
        currentScale,
        start,
        delta
      )
    );
  } else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
  }
}

export function animateFading(
  timestamp,
  container,
  fadeMarkers,
  renderer,
  start,
  delta,
  coef = 1
) {
  var progress;
  if (start === null) start = timestamp;
  progress = timestamp - start;
  var lambda = progress / delta;
  if (lambda > 1) lambda = 1;
  if (lambda < 0) lambda = 0;
  lambda = lambda * (0.4 + lambda * (2.2 + lambda * -1.6));
  fadeMarkers.forEach(function (markerSprite) {
    markerSprite.alpha = coef > 0 ? lambda : 1 - lambda;
  });
  renderer.render(container);
  if (progress < delta) {
    var frame = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      animateFading(
        Date.now(),
        container,
        fadeMarkers,
        renderer,
        start,
        delta,
        coef
      )
    );
  } else {
    if (coef < 0) container.removeChild(...fadeMarkers);
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
  }
}
```

What I'm trying:

```
export class MyRendering {
  constructor(container, tick, renderer) {
    this.container = container;
    this.tick = tick;
    this.renderer = renderer;
    this.ids = [];
  }

  addId(id) {
    if (!this.ids.includes(id)) this.ids.push(id);
  }

  removeId(id) {
    if (this.ids.includes(id)) {
      var index = this.ids.indexOf(id);
      this.ids.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  setTick(tick) {
    this.tick = tick;
  }

  startIntervalRendering() {
    this.run = true;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('render', Date.now())
      this.renderer.render(this.container);
    }, this.tick);
  }

  stopIntervalRendering(id) {
    this.removeId(id);
    if (!this.ids.length) {
      this.run = false;
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }
}

// rAF
export function animateScaling(
  timestamp,
  container,
  myRendering,
  targetScale,
  currentScale,
  start,
  delta
) {
  var progress;
  if (start === null) start = timestamp;
  progress = timestamp - start;
  var lambda = progress / delta;

  if (lambda > 1) lambda = 1;
  lambda = lambda * (0.4 + lambda * (2.2 + lambda * -1.6));
  container.children.forEach(function (markerSprite) {
    markerSprite.scale.set(
      currentScale + lambda * (targetScale - currentScale)
    );
  });

  if (!myRendering.run) {
    myRendering.startIntervalRendering();
  }
  if (progress == 0) myRendering.addId(start);

  if (progress < delta) {
    var frame = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      animateScaling(
        Date.now(),
        container,
        myRendering,
        targetScale,
        currentScale,
        start,
        delta
      )
    );
  } else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
    myRendering.stopIntervalRendering(start);
  }
}

export function animateFading(
  timestamp,
  container,
  fadeMarkers,
  myRendering,
  start,
  delta,
  coef = 1
) {
  var progress;
  if (start === null) start = timestamp;
  progress = timestamp - start;
  var lambda = progress / delta;
  if (lambda > 1) lambda = 1;
  if (lambda < 0) lambda = 0;
  lambda = lambda * (0.4 + lambda * (2.2 + lambda * -1.6));
  fadeMarkers.forEach(function (markerSprite) {
    markerSprite.alpha = coef > 0 ? lambda : 1 - lambda;
  });

  if (!myRendering.run) {
    myRendering.startIntervalRendering();
  }
  if (progress == 0) myRendering.addId(start);

  if (progress < delta) {
    var frame = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      animateFading(
        Date.now(),
        container,
        fadeMarkers,
        myRendering,
        start,
        delta,
        coef
      )
    );
  } else {
    if (coef < 0) container.removeChild(...fadeMarkers);
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
    myRendering.stopIntervalRendering(start);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, great intuition. Gather up the stuff that needs rendering and render them in a single requestAnimationFrame. The idea is to have RAF running in a loop, each time it runs your “rendering your state”. You can then simplify the rest of your code by separating state and rendering: the RAF always does the same thing, and your state tells it what that is.

Comment: @Graham-P-Heath Thanks a lot for your answer! Is it means I need to have 3+1 rAF: 3 rAFs for changing state and other one for rendering? it might be better to change state without rAF. So I need to launch rAF (for rendering) when at least 1 type of transformation begins and stop when there aren't any type of transformation which active currently. Probably rAF shouldn't depend of current time and just do its job. (Sorry for my English)

Comment: @AlexanderBaikalov About separation of state changes and rendering: please see first part of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760156/3174731

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**: Unfortenally FPS still not stable.

Looks like I've found a solution. I will be glad to hear any comments

```
  constructor(container, renderer) {
    this.container = container;
    this.renderer = renderer;
    this.ids = [];
  }

  addId(id) {
    if (!this.ids.includes(id)) this.ids.push(id);
  }

  removeId(id) {
    if (this.ids.includes(id)) {
      var index = this.ids.indexOf(id);
      this.ids.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  startIntervalRendering() {
    this.run = true;
    this.frame = requestAnimationFrame(() => animate(this));
    // var frame =  ???
  }

  stopIntervalRendering(id) {
    this.removeId(id);
    if (!this.ids.length) {
      this.run = false;
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.frame);
      // maybe need to call cAF
    }
  }
}

function animate(ctx) {
  // console.log(ctx.run)
  ctx.renderer.render(ctx.container);
  if (ctx.run) var frame = requestAnimationFrame(() => animate(ctx));
  else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
  }
}

// transformations
export function transformScaling(
  timestamp,
  container,
  myRendering,
  targetScale,
  currentScale,
  start,
  delta
) {
  var progress;
  if (start === null) start = timestamp;
  progress = timestamp - start;
  var lambda = progress / delta;

  if (lambda > 1) lambda = 1;
  lambda = lambda * (0.4 + lambda * (2.2 + lambda * -1.6));
  container.children.forEach(function (markerSprite) {
    markerSprite.scale.set(
      currentScale + lambda * (targetScale - currentScale)
    );
  });

  if (!myRendering.run) {
    myRendering.startIntervalRendering();
  }
  if (progress == 0) myRendering.addId(start);

  if (progress < delta) {
    var frame = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      transformScaling(
        Date.now(),
        container,
        myRendering,
        targetScale,
        currentScale,
        start,
        delta
      )
    );
  } else {
    myRendering.stopIntervalRendering(start);
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame)
  }
}

export function transformFading(
  timestamp,
  container,
  fadeMarkers,
  myRendering,
  start,
  delta,
  coef = 1
) {
  var progress;
  if (start === null) start = timestamp;
  progress = timestamp - start;
  var lambda = progress / delta;
  if (lambda > 1) lambda = 1;
  if (lambda < 0) lambda = 0;
  lambda = lambda * (0.4 + lambda * (2.2 + lambda * -1.6));
  fadeMarkers.forEach(function (markerSprite) {
    markerSprite.alpha = coef > 0 ? lambda : 1 - lambda;
  });

  if (!myRendering.run) {
    myRendering.startIntervalRendering();
  }
  if (progress == 0) myRendering.addId(start);

  if (progress < delta) {
    var frame = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      transformFading(
        Date.now(),
        container,
        fadeMarkers,
        myRendering,
        start,
        delta,
        coef
      )
    );
  } else {
    myRendering.stopIntervalRendering(start);
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame)
    if (coef < 0) container.removeChild(...fadeMarkers);
  }
}
```