# Clear canvas and redraw it when data change using PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pixi.js

I'm new in PIXI.js and my question is likely to be very basic but I still haven't find a solution. In my project in Vue I use PIXI to animate huge amount of objects moving along paths:

```
data() {
    return {
        app: new PIXI.Application({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            transparent: true
        }),
        currentYear: 2021,
        // ...other data...
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.width = d3.select(this.$refs.container).node().getBoundingClientRect().width
    this.height = d3.select(this.$refs.container).node().getBoundingClientRect().height
    this.visualizeStuff()
},
methods: {
    visualizeStuff() {
        this.$el.appendChild(this.app.view)
        this.app.renderer.resize(this.width, this.height)

        // ...some code where I filter the dataset using this.currentYear...
        for (let i = 0; i < filteredData.length; i++) {
            // ...some code...
            let path = new PIXI.Graphics()
                path.lineStyle(1, 0xff0000, 0)
                this.pathGenerator(filteredData[i].geometry, path)
                path.endFill()
                this.app.stage.addChild(path)

            let items = []                
            let item = PIXI.Sprite.from(require("images/item.png"))
                items.push(plane)
                this.app.stage.addChild(item)
            // ...visualize items along paths using GSAP...
        }
    },
    // ...other methods...
}
```

Everything works fine, the problem appears when some prop changes and I have to filter data and redraw visualization. And here the question is: how to do it? Now the new objects based on newly filtered data are adding up to previously existed

```
watch: {
    params: function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal.someValue == this.target) {
            this.currentYear = newVal.year
            // I guess next I have to clear the canvas somehow
            // I tried this.app.renderer.destroy(true),
            // this.app.renderer.clean(0, 0), but haven't succeeded
            this.visualizeStuff()
        }
    }
}
```

The additional question is whether it possible to set a transition here? Lets say remove objects based on the old data changing their opacity to 0 during a split second and draw the new objects the same way changing opacity from 0 to 1

Comment: Pixi.js is a fairly "low-level" tool used to show stuff on screen - and is specialized in it. This means that is shouldnt be mixed with lets say "business logic" or "game logic" if you will. You can check my answer to other question to see more info about such separation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760156/3174731

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear a `Pixi.Graphics` object, you can use the [clear](https://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#clear) function.

So in your case, you seem to have it called `path`, so it would be:

```js
path.clear();
```

You will obviously have to have some way to iterate over the paths.

Comment: clear removes the path, but i can't redraw a path to the same graphic object after using clear().

Comment: I’m unsure of what you mean. [Here is my implementation](https://github.com/12Thanjo/virtuosity/blob/87b586e98e78222d47bd1d0f8aaed8f89fd1866f/virtuosity/graphics.js#L115), and hopefully it can help you.