# Performance Issues with PixiJs Game

Tags: typescript, webpack, optimization, async-await, pixi.js

I am making a simple 2D game using PixiJS, typescript, and Webpack. The game works great on a desktop but when playing it on a mobile browser, the FPS drops to ~20 FPS which is obviously not ideal.

Pseudo-code for my game:

```
import { Application } from 'pixi.js'
const app = new Application()

app.ticker.add((delta)=>gameUpdate(delta))

function gameUpdate(delta){
    updatePhysics(delta);
    moveBackground(delta);
    checkCollisions(delta);
}
```

Should I make my functions asynchronous? How do I ensure that there are not race conditions in the shared state?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You should start by measuring which part of your program is slowest. Measure execution times of each part of logic in `gameUpdate` - so how much takes `updatePhysics` , how much `moveBackground` and how much `checkCollisions`. Save slowest times, and avarage times. Then when you know that for example `updatePhysics` is slowest then dig deeper into parts of logic inside that method etc. then you should have clearer picture about which parts need to be optimized.

Comment: Also maybe before that you should check how much fps do you get on mobile if you dont do anything in `gameUpdate`. So  make `gameUpdate` method empty and check FPS etc - how much do you get? Is more than 20?

Comment: @domis86 I was thinking I could separate the drawing loop from the game logic to increase frames. Could I do that somehow?

Comment: see first part of my answer from last year: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760156/3174731  - it has example code in jsfiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/urvdhw8b/ ) - is for Pixi v5 but with some small changes it could be ported to v7. See functions `gameLogicLoop()` and `animationLoop()`. For v7 you should probably do also as is described in https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Ticker.html#shared to stop the default "Ticker" loop so you can call `renderer.render(stage)` manually only in your custom animation loop.

Comment: After you have control over `renderer.render(stage)` then you can also measure time of this rendering - to see how it compares with times of rest of logic (`updatePhysics` etc)

Comment: Hi, your answer has been very helpful but I have encountered an additional issue.  For the state updates, I require information about the delta time. I have tried using performance.now() and subtracting the past and current values but this method produces results much different from the "delta" value when using the app.ticker.add((delta)=>func) method. How can I accurately measure the delta time? @domis86

Comment: If you have 2 loops which are executed with different frequency (for example game update is 10 FPS, and render loop is 60 FPS) then each loop will have different delta.

Comment: in each loop you need to calculate delta time separately: `newTime = Date.now();
    deltaTime = newTime - oldTime;  oldTime = newTime;`

Comment: @domis86 so I have a working solution but I am not sure why it works... So I tried separating the logic and rendering into separate loops but this did not improve the performance. For some reason though, manually calling the renderer and state update in a ticker did improve performance when I change the max and min FPS values. Any ideas why this works? [github page to the project](https://github.com/gabekole/FlappyBird/tree/dev). Its a game if you want to try it out